# Xorriso command fail when using option -add

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, iso, mkisofs

Im using Xorriso and running this command :

```
   $MKISOFS \
    -iso-level 3 \
    -J -joliet-long \
    -append_partition 2 0xef $UNIONDIR/$EFIIMG \
    -partition_cyl_align all \
    -add "$UNATTENDED_FILE" 'C:\System32\Sysprep' \
    -o "$CFG_ISOPATH" \
    "$UNIONDIR/"
```

the command with populated vars is this :

```
/usr/bin/xorriso -as mkisofs -iso-level 3 -J -joliet-long -append_partition 2 0xef /tmp/union.19/boot-efi.img -partition_cyl_align all -add /tmp/wf_script-Xjc2i3/unattended.xml | 'C:\System32\Sysprep' -o 991cc570-10d9-11ec-818a-5d4c9d0ae440.iso /tmp/union.19/
```

This is the error I'm getting, and it is happening because of the -add option:

```
+ /usr/bin/xorriso -as mkisofs -iso-level 3 -J -joliet-long -append_partition 2 0xef /tmp/union.19/boot-efi.img -partition_cyl_align all -add /tmp/wf_script-eZeXEW/unattended.xml 'C:\System32\Sysprep' -o 3d3839e0-10db-11ec-818a-5d4c9d0ae440.iso /tmp/union.19/
xorriso 1.5.0 : RockRidge filesystem manipulator, libburnia project.

Drive current: -outdev 'stdio:3d3839e0-10db-11ec-818a-5d4c9d0ae440.iso'
Media current: stdio file, overwriteable
Media status : is blank
Media summary: 0 sessions, 0 data blocks, 0 data, 42.2g free
xorriso : FAILURE : -as mkisofs: Unrecognized option '-add'
xorriso : aborting : -abort_on 'FAILURE' encountered 'FAILURE'
+ ok 'Creating new windows ISO'
+ EXITCODE=5
+ '[' 5 = 0 ']'
+ echo 'FAILURE: Creating new windows ISO'
+ exit 5
FAILURE: Creating new windows ISO
+ cleanup
+ purge /tmp/etfsimg19 /tmp/etfsmnt.19 /tmp/lower.19 /tmp/prop.19 /tmp/union.19 /tmp/union.19 /tmp/upper.19 /tmp/work.19
+ cd /tmp
+ for X in "$@"
+ '[' -d /tmp/etfsimg19 ']'
+ for X in "$@"
+ '[' -d /tmp/etfsmnt.19 ']'
+ umount /tmp/etfsmnt.19
+ for X in "$@"
+ '[' -d /tmp/lower.19 ']'
+ umount /tmp/lower.19
+ for X in "$@"
+ '[' -d /tmp/prop.19 ']'
+ umount /tmp/prop.19
+ for X in "$@"
+ '[' -d /tmp/union.19 ']'
+ umount /tmp/union.19
+ for X in "$@"
+ '[' -d /tmp/union.19 ']'
+ umount /tmp/union.19
+ for X in "$@"
+ '[' -d /tmp/upper.19 ']'
+ umount /tmp/upper.19
+ for X in "$@"
+ '[' -d /tmp/work.19 ']'
+ umount /tmp/work.19
+ rm -rf /tmp/etfsimg19 /tmp/etfsmnt.19 /tmp/lower.19 /tmp/prop.19 /tmp/union.19 /tmp/union.19 /tmp/upper.19 /tmp/work.19
```

The reason why i need the -add option is because i need to drop the file unattended.xml into the C:\System32\Sysprep folder in the ISO, so when it will run it will be able to execute the installation by itself.

Any help is very much appreciated

Regards

Danilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `-add` belongs to the native command set of xorriso, which is
not compatible with mkisofs options. (There it would need a finalizing
argument `--` to end its range before the next command word. Given your
goal I would say you would want command `-map`, not `-add`.)
In the mkisofs emulation you can define the target path in the ISO by
giving a "pathspec" of the form `target_path=source_path`.

Paths of files or directories in the ISO have to be given with '/' as
separators. Even then, the path component `C:` will be a directory name
in the ISO. Do you really want it that way ? (I know 0 about MS-Windows.)

With an ISO path that is suitable for your intentions you may achieve
your goal of inserting `$UNATTENDED_FILE` as `$ISO_PATH` by the mkisofs
compatible options

```
-graft-points "$ISO_PATH"="$UNATTENDED_FILE"
```

The text `"$ISO_PATH"="$UNATTENDED_FILE"` should be given after `$UNIONDIR/`
in order to avoid that a file in `$UNIONDIR/` overwrites `"$ISO_PATH"`.
(Of course `"$ISO_PATH"` should not contain `=` characters. They can be
represented by `\=` if really needed.)